# Add new element set to existing XML files via XSLT using variables as attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not really used to working with XSLT, but I want to add a few new elements to an existing XML file that looks like this:

```
    <TEI>
     <teiHeader>
      ...
      <profileDesc/>
      ...
     </teiHeader>
    ...
     <body/>
    </TEI>
```

What I want to add is this (to profileDesc):

```
        <tei:particDesc>
            <tei:listPerson>
                <tei:person role="" ref="{$persons}">
                    <tei:persName></tei:persName>
                </tei:person>
            </tei:listPerson>
            <tei:listOrg>
                <tei:org role="" ref="{$institutions}">
                    <tei:orgName></tei:orgName>
                </tei:org>
            </tei:listOrg>
        </tei:particDesc>
```

So I want to add the particDesc-element and add the distinct values of $persons and $institutions to the ref-attributes.

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity-copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:profileDesc">
        <xsl:variable name="persons" select=".//body//rs[@type='person'][not(.=preceding::*)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="institutions" select=".//body//rs[@type='institution'][not(.=preceding::*)]"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <tei:particDesc>
                <tei:listPerson>
                    <tei:person role="" ref="{$persons}">
                        <tei:persName></tei:persName>
                    </tei:person>
                </tei:listPerson>
                <tei:listOrg>
                    <tei:org role="" ref="{$institutions}">
                        <tei:orgName></tei:orgName>
                    </tei:org>
                </tei:listOrg>
            </tei:particDesc>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
<tei:particDesc xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><tei:listPerson><tei:person role="" ref=""><tei:persName/></tei:person></tei:listPerson><tei:listOrg><tei:org role="" ref=""><tei:orgName/></tei:org></tei:listOrg></tei:particDesc></profileDesc>
```

Desired output:

```
<particDesc>
 <listPerson>
  <person role="" ref="[value of distinct persons-value 1]">
   <persName></persName>
  </person>
  <person role="" ref="[value of distinct persons-value 2]">
   <persName></persName>
  </person>
  ...
 </listPerson>
 <listOrg>
  <org role="" ref="[value of distinct institutions-value 1]">
   <orgName></orgName>
  </org>
  <org role="" ref="[value of distinct institutions-value 2]">
   <orgName></orgName>
  </org>
  ...
 </listOrg>
</particDesc>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your paths are not selecting anything? Do the input elements have a namespace your XSLT doesn't take into account? If you have e.g. `xmlns="http://example.com/"` on the input elements or they have a prefix of a namespace declaration or there is a DTD setting up a default namespace then your XSLT code has to declare that namespace; in XSLT 2 or 3 you can use e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/"`, in XSLT 1 you have to declare a prefix (you seem to do that already) and use it e.g. `.//TEI:body//TEI:rs[@type='person'][not(.=preceding::*)]`. It might help us if you show the XML

Comment: Thanks, this helped (even though I discovered some more bugs in the meantime, so if anyone would like to reuse the code: be aware, you should add a for-each loop and adapt the variables if you want to do the same as me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input `<profileDesc/>` element is empty, so `.//body` selects nothing. Perhaps you meant `select="//body"`, or `select="../../body"`, or, as Martin suggests, `select="../../tei:body"`.

Comment: Thank you, I gladly already solved the problem by adding the namespace-prefixes.